# Exporting million rows in postgres/Pgadmin but return empty CSV file

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv, pgadmin-4

I did a union all for 12 tables and the output is around 5.7 million rows. And when i tried to download it then save it as a CSV file, it says 0 bytes. Can someone explain what should i do about it please ???

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUxlz.png)

Comment: Include the steps you took save it a CSV file. Present information as text **not images**.

Comment: Better solution would be to use `\copy` in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).